# How to fix the Anaconda linter showing errors for f-strings in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

The error shown is simply "[E]" so I'm not sure how to exempt this error in the Anaconda preferences.

e.g. the linter error for `print(f"Hello, world!")` says "*[E] invalid syntax*"

Comment: The `[E]` is for error.

Comment: truly an annoying error....

Answer (score 31):

Edit your users preferences of Anaconda and add this:

```
"python_interpreter": "python3",
```

I have read somewhere that it was a known bug of python. It's fixed in version 3.6.3, so maybe you have to update your python version also. Mine was 3.6.3, so I don't know if it's necessary to update.

Comment: for mac using Homebrew, a link to the alias did the trick:
"python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3.6",

Comment: Thanks so much! Was annoying me so much. PS: I had to set mine to "python3.6" because my python3 points to python3.5 for good reasons.

Comment: While you're at it, you might also want to set "pep8_ignore": "W503" in order to prevent the (incorrect) complaints about PEP8 line breaks before binary operators